# sso login using oauth2/OIDC without redirects - possible?

Tags: php, single-sign-on, openid-connect

I'm trying to figure out what I need to do for implementing SSO.
So basically I'm building:

a) php website (example.com)
b) android app (com.android.example)

Site and app will have a login form + social login buttons to authenticate via twitter, FB etc.

What im not understanding is - how do people implement login form on site that authenticates against OIDC server without redirects? If I understand it correctly - OIDC flow calls for redirecting person to different website for login... How do I avoid that so user experience is seamless for login with my personal OIDC server (for other social logins like google - I dont'really care about redirects)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have a login form and collect user credentials, you would be able to take advantage of the "Resource Owner Credentials" flow, AKA the "password" grant type. This is a type that is defined by the OAuth specification and is inherited by OIDC.

The password grant type allows the OAuth/OIDC client to directly send the user’s credentials to the OAuth/OIDC server. This grant is a good user experience for trusted first party clients both on the web and in native device applications.

You basically send a request to `/accessToken` endpoint for your OIDC server, supplying:

```
grant_type=password&client_id=ID&client_secret=<SECRET>&username=USERNAME&password=PASSWORD
```

More info available at: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.3